# Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, jasper-reports

I'm working on a Java project that uses Jasperreports. I worked several times in other projects using the same technology, and i had the same problem when trying to print a report in Unix environments.

My project uses:

- JBoss 4.2.3.GA
- Java 1.6
- Jasperreports 4.7.0

The exception thrown is:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

I found a common solution to solve this issue and ir really works:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

However, I want to understand how Jasper works with fonts, and how it searches this fonts installed in Unix environments. Maybe a better question is: how JVM handles native fonts? Can anyone give me a detailed explanation on this subject? How are system fonts made available for the JVM in runtime?

Comment: You should read about [Font Extensions](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) mechanism. You can also find more details in *JasperReports Ultimate Guide*. For better understanding you can explore the source files of *JR engine*

Comment: Is there any source for this in JVM docs?

Comment: I found this link interesting explaining how the JVM works with fonts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/font.html. I think this is the information I was looking for.

Comment: @AlexK I have the same problem of OP and I use JasperReports font extensions, thus my font files are in a jar within my application. I don't get why JVM can't find them. In lots of posts people suggest installing the font in the OS, but this would break the purpose of font extensions.

Comment: @barbosa Are you using JasperReports Font extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java asks the OS to provide the fonts. How that works depends on the OS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial states its is installed on MS-Windows and MAC OSX

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go through the hassle of downloading jars and what not, just go to software-center and click install **Ubuntu restricted extras**. This package will install not only MS Fonts but other supports for applications with restricted copyright.

This works for Ubuntu Systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue on Jasper 5.0. I have followed the steps below:

1. Place the `jasper-fonts.jar`;
2. Install the missing fonts in the linux;
3. Restart the JBoss server.

Answer (score 0):

Update for year 2015:

Add this to (or uncomment in) /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
```

Then run this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

Answer (score 0):

for OpenSuse

validate the fonts is no aviable on SO
fc-list | grep "Arial"

install the followin rpm 
sudo rpm -ivh msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm

or Download from page:

http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f11.html#ttf

Install the rpm

validate again 
fc-list | grep "Arial"

Restart your aplication server

Answer (score 0):

this save my day !

http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/usage.html#Reports_with_custom_fonts

**Reports with custom fonts**

*Jaspersoft Studio has an option to create a jar file of your fonts. Just put this jar file into the jdbc folder of JasperStarter.*