# Jasper: Arial' is not available to the JVM

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, report

I am getting this error on Linux machine I want set the font name  to "SansSerif" which installed on Linux machine but don't know why it always get "Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM.".

In code I am setting "SansSerif"

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font", "true");
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name", "SansSerif");
```

**Limitaions**:

- I could not install font on linux.
- I could not place any font    jar with my code.

I need any solution through JAVA code.

**StackTrace**:

```
pring: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcont
```

**StackTrace 2**:
After implementing `net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=true` in the `jasperreports.properties` I get this error.

```
[27/01/15 14:55:08:779 GMT] 000000b7 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[spring]: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontUtil.checkAwtFont(JRFontUtil.java:358)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledText.getAwtAttributedString(JRStyledText.java:225)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.AbstractTextRenderer.render(AbstractTextRenderer.java:264)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportText(JRPdfExporter.java:2075)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:778)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:738)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:616)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:364)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(JasperExportManager.java:163)
```

Comment: Set the `net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=true` in the `jasperreports.properties` file or as a custom property in that particular report template. If your report doesn't really need Arial, change the font in your report.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425612/font-arial-is-not-available-to-the-jvm)

Comment: Federico Sierra  We have already implemented this solution but this works in windows not on Linux thanks. Can you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: @Federico Sierra. After implementing your solution. I get exception. Kindly check StackTrace 2. Thanks

Comment: What version of jasperreport are using?